# Calling javascript on complete of commandbutton action

Tags: javascript, jsf, commandbutton

How can I call a JavaScript function after completion of command button action?

I'm using JSF 1.0.

Comment: Please provide some more information ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just let JSF conditonally render the desired script.

E.g.

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.submitted}">
        <script>alert('Form was submitted!');</script>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

with

```
private boolean submitted;

public void submit() {
    // ...
    submitted = true;
}

public boolean isSubmitted() {
    return submitted;
}
```